# How to reference Bokeh quad values on-select within callback

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to extract values from quads when I click on them using `TapTool`

The following code works for a `hover` tool but not for `tap`.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, CustomJS, ColumnDataSource

source =  generate_column_data_source()
quad_plot = generate_quad_plot(source )

code = ''' var hovered_ind = cb_data.index['1d'].indices[0];
    var data = source.data
    console.log(hovered_ind)
    if(hovered_ind != undefined){
        console.log('inside', hovered_ind)
        var top = data['top'][hovered_ind]
        var bottom = data['bottom'][hovered_ind]
        var left = data['left'][hovered_ind]
        var right = data['right'][hovered_ind]
        console.log(top, bottom, left, right)
    } '''

callback = CustomJS(code=code, args={'source': source})

quad_plot.add_tools(TapTool( callback=callback))  

show(quad_plot)
```

It seems that `cb_data.index['1d'].indices[0];` exists for hover interactions, but not for tap-selection interactions.

For tap-selection, `cb_data` has a single attribute named `geometry`, that gives me `x`,`y`,`vx`,and `vy`points.

I do not believe these parameters to be exact enough to guarantee efficient indexing/lookup of values from my source.

Is there any way to get that precise of an index with `TapTool`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: in modern Bokeh it is just `source.selected.indices` (no more `['1d']` etc)

---

Glyphs which are selected with the taptool are accessible through the source.selected attribute. 
To answer your last comment regarding 0d,1d and 2d: For a point glyph you can access it through `source.selected['0d'].indices`, for line like objects '1d', and then multiline/patches glyphs through ['2d']. 
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html (scroll down to selected attribute)

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, TapTool

top = [2, 3, 4]
bottom = [1, 2, 3]
left = [1, 2, 3]
right = [1.2, 2.5, 3.7]
data = {'top':top, 'bottom':bottom, 'left':left, 'right':right}
source = ColumnDataSource(data)
quad_plot = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
quad_plot.quad(top="top", bottom="bottom", left="left",
    right="right",source=source, color="#B3DE69")


tap_code = """
    var selected= source.selected['1d'].indices
    console.log('tap, you selected:', selected)
"""
tap_callback = CustomJS(code = tap_code, args={'source': source})
quad_plot.add_tools(TapTool(callback=tap_callback))  

show(quad_plot)
```

Comment: Thanks again Okonomiyaki. Can you find any reference of this in the docs?

Comment: Its a combination of the TapTool documentation (tells you that tap tool can select glyphs), JS callback examples (various callbacks on tools, etc...) and source documentation (tells you about selected glyphs and how to access indicies).